# Find out on what web server a site is running

Tags: webserver

I've found a few questions here on how to find out what technologies a page is using; however, none of the solutions proposed  how to find out whether the page was e.g. running on a Apache HTTP Server or on Microsoft ISS.

Is it possible to find that out? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not universally possible, no. In some specific cases, you can look at the [`Server` HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses), but it's not watertight and it's really up to the server to send to "honest" headers. There's nothing to say that an IIS server couldn't send this back:

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Additionally, proxies/load balancers/etc. could theoretically strip that information away completely.